# How to load 3d models using ARToolkit for Android in java (not native c++)

Tags: java, android, 3d, artoolkit

How to render `.obj` 3d models using [ARToolkit](https://artoolkit.org) library for **Android in Java**. (or any other 3d models formats like `.dae`)

Doing the same thing using *Native c++* and ARToolkit wrapper is easy and they have examples for it, but I didn't find any thing in [ARToolkit documentation](https://artoolkit.org/documentation/) or [examples](https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/tree/master/AndroidStudioProjects) to help me render 3d models in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a 3D Engine to render the models, I did implement the connection between jPCT-AE and ARToolKit a while ago, you can check it here: https://github.com/plattysoft/ArToolKitJpctBaseLib

It is not 100% complete, since on some resolutions the FOV is not correct, but most of the times it is fine.

There are also some examples on how to use it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But is there any way to render models using OpenGL in Java like ARToolkit native examples (using OpenGL in c++) ?

Comment: You have a GL Object on the renderer, so you can do whatever you want with it. Loading models is not a trivial task, that's why I suggested leveraging on an engine to do so, the native example leverages it on OSG.

Comment: I did try your project and really good work man; it made my life easier. It will be amazing if you continue maintaining it :)